# Why are my AngularJS, Karma / Jasmine tests running so slowly?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I have some simple karma / jasmine unit-tests that run against an angularjs app. I use the latest version of Chrome and run my tests from within the WebStorm IDE.

Sometimes the test suite runs very quickly (0.24 seconds)

Sometimes exactly the same test suite against exactly the same code runs very slowly (120 seconds)

I have tried every common sense fix. I have scoured the web to try and discover what I am doing wrong.

Why do my tests run so slowly?

Comment: Even my experience tells me Karma with Chrome (or Phantom JS driver) is very slow. On the moment you hit Enter, it takes 25 seconds to build, 5-6 seconds to bootstrap and another 1.8 seconds (to run 1 test). Even when I press save there is a delay of several seconds before it runs the test....I suspect a SSD would help.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

The answer turns out to be very simple.

I am using Chrome to run the karma server. When you first start the karma server an instance of Chrome is started as a maximised window. So naturally you minimise this so you can see your tests running.

The problem is that Chrome starves any minimised or secondary tabs (switched tabs) of CPU cycles.

Therefore, if you minimise the browser instance running the karma server, or just switch  to a different tab, then the karma server is severely starved of CPU and the tests take a long time to complete.

The solution is to keep the karma tab active. The browser window can be hidden behind other windows but the karma tab *must be the selected tab* and the browser *must not be minimised*.

Following these simple rules will ensure that your tests always run at full speed.

Comment: Wow!  I can't tell you how many hours I've wasted waiting for tests to run!  I'll add here that it doesn't seem like the window has to be visible.  Simply not minimizing it seems to be working.

Comment: OMFG! Nice catch! That said, is there something in Chrome we can disable to turn this CPU-saving function off ?

Comment: Unless you absolutely need Chrome, I'd suggest a headless browser like PhantomJS so that you do not have this problem

Comment: But what about this with headless browser?

Answer (score 0):

Biofractal has answered his own question and you could do that. You could also set up your tests to run in PhantomJS or Chrome Headless which basically allows the unit tests to run only in your command line, thus removing an affects with your actual browsers.

Comment: Just to warn people, PhantomJS seems to run a lot slower than Chrome and Chrome Headless. It takes almost a second per test on our CI server which is totally unacceptable.

Comment: PhantomJS is now suspended (deprecated), ChromeHeadless is probably what you are looking for. If you do use Phantom you may find some cool new JS features you are using aren't supported or need a polyfill.

Comment: [Puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) is a better option considering that it can be added as a dev dependency for you project. This removes the need to install Chrome in the CI servers.