# profiling memory leaks in karma-runner/jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, memory-leaks, jasmine, karma-runner

I have an AngularJS application with about 2000 unit tests which consume a lot of memory. Once tests launched, they run pretty fast (in Chrome) until memory consumption hits 1.5GB at which point every test starts to take about 3 seconds.

Now, I'm pretty damn sure this is **not** related to [Why are my AngularJS, Karma / Jasmine tests running so slowly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19683846/why-are-my-angularjs-karma-jasmine-tests-running-so-slowly).

At this point I have no idea if it's the tests that are leaking or the application itself. I would like to profile the test execution.

I've read [unit-tests karma-runner/jasmine profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687499/unit-tests-karma-runner-jasmine-profiling/20725884#20725884) and am trying to do the following:

> You can use localhost:9876/debug.html and profile the memory. Check the memory before executing (after Jasmine executed all the `describe()` blocks and collected the tests) and then after executing the tests - it should be the same.

But how can this be done?

I don't really understand how it is possible to check before and after. Can I somehow pause the tests execution? Is jasmine able to tell me when it's "collected the tests" and wait for me to do the profiling?

Or is there any other approach?

Comment: Have the same problem. We have 4000+ unit tests and actually browsers start crashing: Chrome disconnects from Karma, Firefox crashes around 4100. I did some memory profiling in Chrome and it looks to me like jasmine is keeping stuff alive/rooted. Did you ever solve your problem?

Comment: No 100% sure but I think this question is related with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32998442/angularjs-unit-testing-memory-leaks

Answer (score 5):

This is not a full answer but just "*thinking out loud*"...

1. I would start isolating a suite first.
2. Then I'd start to have a look at the [Chrome Console API](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api) - so focus on one browser only for the moment .
3. Now in each `beforeEach` or `afterEach` trigger and shutdown the profiler (using a a suite + test name for each profiling): see the [`console.profile(\[label\])`](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api#consoleprofilelabel) and [`console.profileEnd()`](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api#consoleprofileend) calls.
4. At this point you don't need to stop anything to run the profiling, at the end of the testing you'll have all the results (with labels).

Once found the place where the memory goes up you can focus the area and probably start debugging in a more specific way...

Comment: It would be awesome to do it in global `beforeAll`/`afterAll` blocks, but `console.profile` does only CPU profiling and afaik there's no heap profiling api. Or is there?

Comment: If you're interested in memory the closest thing is "console.timeline", and see the memory consuming.

Comment: console.profile/End helped me find a leak. A setInterval was used in the initalization of a service, which was instantiated in all tests.

Answer (score 0):

We are seeing similar issues in recent Chrome, though we are using Mocha. Interestingly, you can set a debugger and the memory still climbs... This makes me consider that its not our code or even JS heap size, seems like a browser bug?

Comment: I have read somewhere that Chrome has a very aggressive object attribute caching strategy. Check for elements which take up the most space. It might be the template strings.