# Speed up tests run in Chrome

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome, karma-runner

This is based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30806747/971592) where it was discovered that when Chrome is not in the foreground, the tests run really slow. Anyone know how to get around that so I can continue to use Chrome, but don't have to keep it in the foreground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this, but there is [an issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=485425) to bring support for it back. Follow that for updates.

Answer (score 2):

Run chrome in headless mode. I've seen a fantastic performance improvement.

```
gulp.task('test-headless-chrome', function (done) {
  process.env.DISPLAY=':95';

  withXvfb(function(stop) {
    server.start({
      configFile: __dirname + '/../karma/karma.conf.js',
      singleRun: true
    }, function() {
      stop();
      done();
    });
  });
});

function withXvfb(op) {
    var child = spawn('Xvfb', [':95', '-ac', '-screen', '0', '1600x1200x24'], {
            stdio: 'inherit'
    });

    setTimeout(op(function() {
        console.log("Killing Xvfb...")
        child.kill();
    }),3000);
}
```

Comment: Yes! I just noticed this yesterday! Hooray!

Answer (score 2):

A more manual trick that works on Macs is to put the chrome window in full screen mode in a space that is off screen.

It takes an extra click every time you start the test suite, but if you are watching the tests then you only have to do it once. You get all the performance improvements and don't have to worry about keeping chrome in the foreground.